# Where is the pid stored?

Tags: c++, process, pid

I have the following question in an assignment:
In every **one second** a process calls the following function:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string create_file_name(time_t timestamp) {
 pid_t pid = getpid();
 string s = “results-” + to_string(pid) + to_string(timestamp);
 return s;
}
```

The question is where does the kernel store the process PID?
there are 5 different answers:
user's stack \ kernel's stack \ heap \ PCB \ runqueue

Now generally, I know that the PID is stored inside the PCB but in this case, should it also be stored inside the user's stack? (since it's a local variable).
The question seems to have only one answer, so I am quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

As said from the manpage :

> From glibc version 2.3.4 up to and including version 2.24, the glibc
> wrapper function for getpid() cached PIDs, with the goal of avoiding
> additional system calls when a process calls getpid() repeatedly.
> Normally this caching was invisible, but its correct operation relied
> on support in the wrapper functions for fork(2), vfork(2), and
> clone(2): if an application bypassed the glibc wrappers for these
> system calls by using syscall(2), then a call to getpid() in the
> child would return the wrong value (to be precise: it would return
> the PID of the parent process).  In addition, there were cases where
> getpid() could return the wrong value even when invoking clone(2) via
> the glibc wrapper function.  (For a discussion of one such case, see
> BUGS in clone(2).)  Furthermore, the complexity of the caching code
> had been the source of a few bugs within glibc over the years.
>
> Because of the aforementioned problems, since glibc version 2.25, the
> PID cache is removed: calls to getpid() always invoke the actual
> system call, rather than returning a cached value.
>
> On Alpha, instead of a pair of getpid() and getppid() system calls, a
> single getxpid() system call is provided, which returns a pair of PID
> and parent PID.  The glibc getpid() and getppid() wrapper functions
> transparently deal with this.  See syscall(2) for details regarding
> register mapping.

It depend on the `glibc` you use. In fact in some version `glibc` mantains a cache of the pid, while in some versions it repetedly call the syscall to get the pid of the process if you want to know how the system call work is suggest you to see the kernel code.

You can find the `getpid()` function at this [link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/kernel/sys.c). ( you can change the kernel version and navigate all the source code to rebuild how the `getpid()` syscall works.